# Loop the recored macro in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cC_Zm-tW9joJ4MmeDTY_pnWE7VzW4ZrBI3tLY5aGJE0/edit?usp=sharing)[Sheet 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfuHY.png)I have created a crypto analysis sheet in Google sheets, where it takes the data from Investing.com.
In a `sheet1` I have all the info for a single coin, now I don't want to check each one at a time.
So in `sheet2`, i placed the complete Coins list. I recorded a macro with copy pasting the required data from `sheet1` to `sheet2`. Now I want to do the same for all remaining 100 coins. How to loop this. Kindly answer. I don't have knowledge in Codes but trying my best.

I tried with this below code. But while running macro, this below function not run.

```
function loop() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Analysis_USD');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Screener').getRange('B3:B102').getValues();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(data[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    if (sheet.getRange('B102').getValue() == 'Yes'){
      output.push([data[i][0]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,12,output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}
```

[From the Coin list(sheet2) i am pasting one coin to the A2 of sheet 1 and it calculates and the result has to be paste in the sheet 2, for 1st coin i have recorded the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4jG.png)

Comment: Can you show some sample data regarding your code, I think quite ez to solve one, just I am not sure about the expected output

Comment: Thanks for replying, i have added the images with explanation. please check

Answer (score 1):

Please try to following code modification and check if it does work, as it need to `Transpose` your column value into row value to be able to write to `Screener` sheet, it work when I test it for single coin execution, the looping I did not test for it but it work in the same logic:

```
    function loop() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Analysis_USD');
      var data = ss.getSheetByName('Screener').getRange('B3:B102').getValues();
     
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(data[i][0]);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        Utilities.sleep(10000);
        if (sheet.getRange('B102').getValue() == 'Yes'){
       var result = sheet.getRange(10,2,13,1).getValues();
        }
        
      //Transpose Column to row value 
      var newArray = result[0].map(function(col, i) { 
          return result.map(function(row) { 
            return row[i] 
          })
        })
      ss.getSheetByName('Screener').getRange(3 + i,4, 1,result.length).setValues(newArray);
    }
}
```

Let's try with single row update on the `Bitcoin` first, because I can perform the entire row value updating using `Column Value`  from `Analysis`, I am doing the testing based same data from your worksheet :

```
function loop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Analysis_USD');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Screener').getRange('B3:B102').getValues();
 
var result = sheet.getRange(10,2,13,1).getValues();
   var newArray = result[0].map(function(col, i) { 
          return result.map(function(row) { 
            return row[i] 
          })
        })
 ss.getSheetByName('Screener').getRange(3 ,4, 1,result.length).setValues(newArray);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the blow error at the line 
//Transpose Column to row value 
      var newArray = result[0].map(function(col, i) {
Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Try perform single updating with my above code, It is exactly the same code without looping, you should be able to past the test. I guess you may need to replace the `Transpose (col, i)` to `(col, x) & row[x]` as the variable is same as you looping.

Comment: Thanks, Looping is working now for 1 side, the coins are copy and pasting in the Analysis Sheet, but required data's are not copy and pasting and transposing to the Screener page.
Sorry for silly questions, i dont have knowledge in codes...so..!!

Comment: Which part you are getting problem, try do without looping first and test for `Bitcoin` one the `row 3`, if it is working, then continue to use `looping`. What is the result after you run without looping on my second asnwer?

Comment: withoutloop row 3 is working fine. When i included the loop function, i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ( after changing Transpose (col, i) to (col, x) & row[x]  also)

Comment: I guess the problem is after you `Flush()` & `Utilities.sleep(10000)` on  first coin, the data did not update but all gone, because based on your original code I don't really see you are updating `Analysis` column value based on different coin since the code ? And that part is abit beyond my knowledge to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, actually after pasting the coin name, google is taking data from another website, hence the sleep code. No worries, i will try something....Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Sure, hope you may combine it to work one day, accept the answer if solve :)